# Get all records from earliest month in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I haven't used MS access in over ten years.  I've looked at various sites and while I can find information on min and max, I can't find the answer to this one.

I have two tables, one archival and one current.  Each time it's run, I need to take the oldest month's records and append them on to the archival table, then delete them from the current table.

If I can just figure out the select statement to return the range of the oldest month, I can do the rest.

So, I need....

```
Select * 
From MyTable
Where ????
```

something that qualifies it as the oldest month

```
order by product_Id
```

Comment: `Group By` and `Having Min(date)` should give you a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses the fact that MS Access really does a `top with ties`:

```
select top 1 t.*
from mytable as t
order by datepart("yyyy", datecol) asc, datepart("m", datecol) asc
```

A more typical method would be an `inner join`:

```
select t.*
from mytable as t inner join
     (select min(datecol) as mindc
      from mytable
     ) as tt
     on datepart("yyyy", t.datecol) = datepart("yyyy", tt.mindc) and
        datepart("m", t.datecol) = datepart("m", tt.mindc);
```